# creating osascript one-line scripts, on mac osx 10.10.2

Tags: osascript

I'm new to terminal scripts and I'm trying to convert

```
osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" 
do script "ssh -t jgreen@dev-jgreen-bs pwd"
end tell'
```

This works with multiline as so but I want a one-line script, but I can't quite get it right. I keep getting a 2741 error, I know it is syntax I am failing with.

I have tried  `/`, `,`, `\n`,`-e`,`&`,`to` as separators.

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to add a few sections to this one line command:

osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal"' -e 'do script "ssh -t jgreen@dev-jgreen-bs pwd"' -e 'end tell'

Each line in an applescript needs to be broken into sections on a single line osascript command in terminal. You add the "-e" for each section and the single apostrophe.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does not work for me. I'm getting error -2741:

syntax error: Expected end of line but found “script”